# How can I program buttons in custom cells according to the selected cell accordingly? ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

So I have a table in notificationsViewController with customs cells. this tableView loads data from jsonSerialization to display data, specifically customerID and checkinID

the custom cell is named checkInCell.m, .xib, and .h. In this custom cell, there are two buttons, one for accepting a check-in and rejecting a check in with API calls. (sample url: api/CheckIn/checkInConfirmation?CustomerID=%@&MerchantID=%@&confirm=%@&CheckInID=%@")

my question is how do i pass the customerID and checkinID from the notificationsViewController for the selected cell to the custom cell buttons, so I can perform accepting and rejecting check-ins?

also, how can i reload the data of the table, because I don't think the code below would work the same if I wanted to reload the data from the checkinCell.

```
[self.notificationsTableview reloadData];
```

i tried doing notificationViewcontroller.notificationsTableView reload data, but I think I'm missing something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: override, after you have accessed your cell with either dequeueCell... or by loading the nib file, you'll need to configure the retrieved cell with the customerID and checkinID and whatever other information is displayed.  Typically your tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath looks something like:

```
-(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    MyCell* cell = [tableView dequeueCellWithReusableIdentifier:@"MyCell"];
    if(!cell)
    {
        cell = .... some other mechanism of loading cell from your nib file
    }

    // configure cell here
    cell.customerID = ...
    cell.checkinID = ...

    return cell;
}
```

Note that the "load from nib file" part is greatly simplified if you use a storyboard as you can use dequeueCellWithReusableIdentifier:forIndexPath: and it will "always" return a cell for you.

The buttons should have their target and action set to the cell itself in your nib file.  Now when the buttons are pressed, a method on the custom cell will be executed and you have access to the data passed in as part of your configuration above.

I'm not sure what your question is about reloadData.  reloadData will cause all all data in the tableview (but not your controller) to be reloaded from the delegate and dataSource (presumably your controller)  If you wish to force just a single section (or row) to be reloaded, there are also reloadSections... and reloadRows... variants.

Comment: sorry, i should be more clear. What I meant is how can I reload the table in notificationsViewController from checkInCell.m

Comment: About the only way I can think of is to set a reference from the cell to the tableview and make sure it gets setup in cellForRowAtIndexPath:  The other possibility is to move all the web logic into the table view controller and set the button's target to the view controller instead of the cell.

Comment: If you're using a storyboard for all of this, the second approach (putting the action in the view controller) is pretty easy to do.  I think that's probably the approach I'd take.

Comment: how can I implement "he other possibility is to move all the web logic into the table view controller and set the button's target to the view controller instead of the cell." how do i hook up the buttons properly?

Comment: Create the layout in a storyboard.  Add an IBAction to the tableviewcontroller .h file.  In interface builder you can ctrl-drag from the button to the tableviewcontroller to set the tableviewcontroller as the target of the action.